# IMPORTJSON to google sheets with an underscore (_) in the column's name

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to use IMPORTJSON to import some data from:

https://templeosrs.com/api/player_stats.php?player=Mikael&date=1639587712

to my google spreadsheet. For some columns, like "Ehp", I can get the value just fine with

> =VALUE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IMPORTJSON(C5)), "select Col2 where Col1 = 'Ehp'"))

where C5 is just a cell with the link above in it. But this doesn't seem to work for any column that has an underscore in it, like "Ehp_rank".

I should say I understand nothing about how any of this works, I'm doing everything by looking at examples I found, then just trial and error. Can someone help me import columns with an underscore?

Also, I'd like to import the "Username", but it's inside that info block and I can't seem to get it right. I've tried "info.Username", changing Col2/1 to Col3/2, but no sucess.

Comment: Can you provide the sample output situation you expect as an image?

Comment: What do you mean by "output situation"? From that table, the value of "Ehp_rank" is 90, that's what I expected to get if I changed "Ehp" to "Ehp_rank" in that formula above, but I get #N/A instead.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill. In your question, you want to retrieve only the value of `90` from `Ehp_rank`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. And no need to apologize, English is also not my first language :)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, how about directly preparing a script as follows?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor. And, please put a custom formula of `=SAMPLE("https://templeosrs.com/api/player_stats.php?player=Mikael&date=1639587712")`. By this, in this case, `90` is returned.

```js
function SAMPLE(url) {
  const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  const obj = JSON.parse(res);
  return obj.data && obj.data.Ehp_rank ? obj.data.Ehp_rank : "";
}
```

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it still says loading but that's probably because I have the spreadsheet fetching too much data. I tested your function on a brand new spreadsheet and it worked perfectly. This was exactly what I wanted, thanks!

Comment: @John Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.